# Compare two XML files using VBScript?

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing

I have **two XML files**, *one is a modified version from the other*. Each has around 80 nodes with each node has around 30 child nodes (yes, around 2400 nodes in total).

The **differences are minor** (usually in the child nodes values) and I need to **get the different nodes out in a separate file**. And if a difference is in a child node, then the child node and its parent should be included in the separate file.

I was going through **a node by node check**. Node from first file with all nodes in the second file. Then second node from first file with all nodes in second file and so one. If match, go and repeat the same for the child nodes for the matched nodes.

The above is really **tedious** and the program takes some time to execute (**around 7000 node comparison**). ***Is there a faster way to compare?***

Comment: Just values has been changed, or also the elements order?

Comment: usually values but also some elements (nodes) may be deleted as well

Comment: I'd suggest you learn how to parse XML files in VBScript: http://www.xmlfiles.com/dom/dom_access.asp

Comment: I know how to parse an XML file, that's not the problem here

Comment: Google XmlDiffPatch and see if it might be an alternative to use that for the comparison and then read the diffgram file that it creates.

Comment: There are a ton of XML differencing tools, some paid, some free some online.  I know this is posted as a VBscript question but there is nothing here about the purpose of the task so one of these other options may be a good one for you depending on things like how often you do this and what needs to be done with the results.

Comment: This is that referenced XML Diff and Patch tool:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx .  However we really need to know more to make any intelligent suggestions on what to use.

Answer (score 0):

As your XML file is quite large, using the DOM Parser would be a bad idea as it will occupy a lot of memory. Another workaround is to implement SAX parser. SAX parser parses an XML file sequentially and uses a handler with three functions (startElement, endElement and characters).

Node by node check is the right idea though. The nested loops will take a lot of time for sure but they will be efficient in terms of memory if used with a SAX Parser.